# Why can my Oracle SQL user not create table, despite having CREATE TABLE permissions?

Tags: oracle, create-table

Why does Oracle SQL not allow a user that has been granted CREATE TABLE privilege to create a table?

If I run

`select * from session_privs;`

When connected as the user, I can verify that I do have the CREATE TABLE **and** the CREATE ANY TABLE privileges.

[Verified perms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfiIb.png)

However, when I try to create a table as the user:

```
create table Course(
CId int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
CName VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

I get the dreaded

```
Error starting at line : 2 in command -
create table c##FACULTYDB.Course(
FId int GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
FName VARCHAR2(50) not null
)
Error report -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

When I run the same create table code as SYS, it works fine. Is there anyone out there that has any ideas of what might cause this to occur??

Comment: How does `create table Course` result in dreaded error for `create table c##FACULTYDB.Faculty`?

Comment: Are you connected as the user `c##FACULTYDB`?

Comment: You say you're trying to create table `COURSE` but you show an error for the table `FACULTY`. This is a confusing. Please **edit your question** and clear up these inconsistencies. Thanks.

Comment: Corrected to reflect the correct error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a table with an identity column you must also have the CREATE SEQUENCE privilege.

For example, if the administrator creates this user:

```
create user test_user identified by test_user;
grant create session, create table, create any table to test_user;
```

This statement will fail for that user:

```
TEST_USER@orclpdb> create table Course(
  2  CId int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  3  CName VARCHAR2(50)
  4  );
create table Course(
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

But after the administrator runs this grant:

```
grant create sequence to test_user;
```

The user will be able to create the table:

```
TEST_USER@orclpdb> create table Course(
  2  CId int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  3  CName VARCHAR2(50)
  4  );

Table created.
```